# How do I do a query that brings up records from the past month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to write a query in MySQL that brings up all fields that have been added in the past month.

```
|First Name |Last Name |Date Added
|John       |Smith     |21-09-2016
|Richard    |Apple     |14-10-2016
|Kent       |Clark     |12-09-2016
```

The query should bring up John and Richard today (18th) but in a week time (25th), it will automatically adjust to only pick up Richard as it was added over a month ago

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went searching and found that this is the way to do it

```
SELECT `Name`, `Date added` 
FROM table WHERE `Date added` > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking of `month` and `year` is a must.

```
SELECT fname,lname 
FROM your_table
WHERE DATEPART(m, date_added) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, date_added) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

Comment: returns an error
#1305 - FUNCTION database_name.DATEPART does not exist

Comment: So everything fine now? @Shadow

Comment: @Shadow Accept the answer so this question be marked as solved and help the others too. :)